# Middle ground between model-based and model-free approaches

Tags: modelling, reinforcement-learning

In the context of the reinforcement learning domain, the dichotomy between model-based (learn a model and used it to determine a controller) and model-free (learn a controller without learning a model) approaches is a contested one.

There are many algorithms that have been developed for both approaches.

My question is, are there any approaches that are *between* model-based and model-free? One example could be to specify a controller that is the combination of a learned controller (when there is sufficient information to do so) and a pre-determined controller based a model (when we cannot learn the controller).